# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject convert json to c# class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

all what i want to make class that have properties slimier to this json.

```
{"code":200,"detected":{"lang":"en"},"lang":"en-ar","text":["hello"]}
```

**i tried many times please help**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and above, you'll find that it can generate this JSON-compatible class for you.

Just copy a sample JSON structure (like the one you posted here), go to any .cs file, and go to `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes`. VS will automatically generate a class for you that your JSON can be deserialized into.

Answer (score 2):

The following model should work:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public Detected Detected { get; set; }
    public string Lang { get; set; }
    public string[] Text { get; set; }
}

public class Detected
{
    public string Lang { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can deserialize to it:

```
string json = ...
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

I find [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) very helpful in converting json samples to C# classes/pocos which I then use with Json.NET.

Comment: This is not an answer.  This kind of thing belongs on your blog

Comment: This is one of the solutions hence an answer to the problem. Certainly nothing to write a blog post about :-)